# get all the values in Sql table using foreach

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, foreach

I need to get all the Ids' from the table "StaffSectionInCharge", it has only two columns StaffId and SectionId, I have values of StaffId and StudentId.....the problem is I can't get the records directly to this table.....am using entity framework and the design of this table is

```
[EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("Model", "StaffSectionInCharge", "Section")]
    public EntityCollection<Section> Sections
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<Section>("Model.StaffSectionInCharge", "Section");
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != null))
            {
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<Section>("Model.StaffSectionInCharge", "Section", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can access this table through staff table like

```
Staff staff = buDataEntities.Staffs.First(s => s.StaffId == StaffId);
Section section = buDataEntities.Sections.First(s => s.SectionId == SectionId);

staff.Sections.Add(section);
buDataEntities.savechanges();
```

like this I can add the records to this StaffSectionInCharge table....

here I want to get all the StaffIds for the corresponding SectionId

I tried getting like

```
DataAccess.Staff staffs = new DataAccess.Staff();

foreach (int staff in staffs.Sections.Select(s=>s.SectionId))
            { 

            }
```

but its not working, can anyone help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var staffIds = buDataEntities.Staffs
    .Where(st => st.Sections.Any(se => se.SectionId == SectionId))
    .Select(st => st.StaffId)
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var staffIds = buDataEntities.Sections
    .Where(se => se.SectionId == SectionId)
    .SelectMany(se => se.Staffs.Select(st => st.StaffId))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Both options should work. If `SectionId` is the primary key of `Section` you can smplify the second code to:

```
var staffIds = buDataEntities.Sections
    .Where(se => se.SectionId == SectionId)
    .Select(se => se.Staffs.Select(st => st.StaffId))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Slauma, can u help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910370/get-values-from-foreign-key-table