# Get values from foreign key table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Am using Entity framework to connect database with my asp.net application. Here I've a `Foreign key table` which has two columns, `StaffId and SectionId`. Here `StaffId` is the Primary key of `Staff` table and `SectionId` is the Primary key of `Sections` table. I have values in this table like

```
StaffId     SectionId
-------     ---------
  1            1
  2            5
  5            8
  1            5
  1            8
```

here I know the `StaffId` and I need to get all the `SectionIds` for this corresponding staffid(eg. 1,5 and 8 for staff 1 here).

If I want to know the details with `First` method, with the known StaffId I can do like,

```
DataObject.Entities dataEntities=new DataObject.Entities();

DataObject.Section section = dataEntities.Sections.First(s=>s.Staffs
                                  .Select(ss=>ss.StaffId).Contains(staffId));
```

with this I can get the information about the `first section` that matches with the `StaffId`.(ex:info about sectionid=1 here)

In the same way I tried to get all the sectionIds for a particular staffId like,

```
List<int> sectionIds = dataEntities.Sections.Where(s => s.Staffs.Where
                       (ss => ss.StaffId == staffId)).Select(sec=>sec.SectionId);
```

but its not working, can anyone help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here I know the StaffId and I need to get all the SectionIds for this
>   corresponding staffid

```
List<int> sectionIds = dataEntities.Sections
    .Where(se => se.Staffs.Any(st => st.StaffId == staffId))
    .Select(se => se.SectionId)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks alot Slauma, I had been strucking here since last evening, so kind of u