# passing value to the null value column in Sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I have a Sections table and in that table I have columns SectionId,CourseId,Name,Capacity....here the CourseId is a null value column and its the Foreignkey here which focuses the Cousrse table....this CourseId column is a newly added one.

I am trying to add records to this table, am using entity framework, in the Entiry framework its showing all the column names except this CourseId, and when I send the datas to this Sections table all the datas except Course Id are stored fine...the value of courseId is stored as Null...

how can I pass the CourseId to this column......can anyone help me here

Comment: I think your edmx is not updated, probably you created the new column and didn't update the edmx, Update it and give it a shot

Comment: Did you update your .edmx file with the database changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If EF is not showing your column, you may need to refresh your model. Start there.

1. Open your .edmx file
2. Right-click on the design surface
3. Choose "Update Model From Database"
4. Follow the instructions.

Comment: No, when I asked my boss, he said something like, its a null value column and asked me to create an object of sections, and pass the value to it.....I dont know how to do this...thats what am asking

Comment: I can access the CourseId like ceEntities.Sections.Select(s=>s.CourseId);.......my question is, can pass the courseid value to this column alone, directly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for ur kind responses, I found out the soultion, I solved the issue like

```
Public int CourseId
{
  get;
  set;
}

DataObject.Entities dataEntities=new DataObject.Entities();

   DataObject.Section section=dataEntities.Sections.CreateSections(0
                                                                    ,Name
                                                                    ,Code
                                                                    ,Capacity);
   section.CourseId=CourseId;
   dataEntities.Sections.AddObject(section);
   dataEntities.SaveChanges();
```